# Hiding div tag when the user clicks outside the div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div tag and I am populating the search results on a custom grid, which is placed inside this divtag.

When a user click on the search button, i am displaying the results in the above mentioned div tag.

I have a requirement to close the above div tag when the user clicks outside the div tag.

It is similar to google search auto comlete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looking for solution in javascript / jquery ?

Comment: i need solution in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Idea

1. Wire an onclick event on body tag to hide the div.
2. Wire an onclick event on div tag and stop event bubbling.

See **[Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)**

To stop event bubbling

In the Microsoft model you must set the event’s cancelBubble property to true.

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true
```

In the W3C model you must call the event’s stopPropagation() method.

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I am using asp.net master page and i cant use body onclick event as it will be using in many other content pages.

At the same time how can i find the html generated id for the div tag used in user control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Madhu: How to find the html generated id for the div tag: Post it as a separate question with source code example of how it is defined.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How to stop event bubbling in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, something like this:

```
$('body').click(function(ev){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('your_result_container_classname') {
    // code to hide result div
    $('body').unbind('click'); // remove event handler. add again when results shown.
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens when the user clicks inside an element in the div element?